# Empty CKEditor -TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ckeditor

I want to empty my Text Area in CKEditor.
I am able to clear the TextArea by using SetData(' '), but for only one time after page loading.

I wrote that `jquery` function in `Onchange` event only.

```
  <%= Html.TextArea("AutoTextNotes", (consentForm != null && consentForm.Notes != null) ? CommonUtil.decodeHTML(consentForm.Notes) : "", new { id = "AutoTextNotes", validateRequest = "false", style = "width: 75%;height: 500px !important;", @class = "fck", onchange = "RemoveValidation('Error_AutoTextNotes');" })%>
```

Jquery Function:-

```
function RemoveValidation(ErrorID) {
        debugger;
        $("#" + ErrorID).css("display", "none");
        var fck_instance = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('AutoTextNotes');
        var imf = fck_instance.GetHTML();
        if (imf.contains("<img")) {
            alert("Sorry, Image Is Not Supported For This TextArea");
            fck_instance.Config.BodyClass = 'shobi';
            fck_instance.SetData('');

            }
         }
```

It would also be helpful is I could remove all image tags in TextArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use

```
$("#id-textarea").val("");
```